# Delete button is deleting random item although I have the right code

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, sql-delete

I have a grid view that gets data from a database. It also has the delete function and is set to delete a row depending on the productID. However when I try to delete a row, yes it is deleting a row but randomly. Not the one I want to delete.

Here is my grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdview"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
    DataKeyNames="ProductID"  OnRowCancelingEdit="gdview_RowCancelingEdit" 
    OnRowDeleting="gdview_RowDeleting" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowDataBound="gdview_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ProductID" SortExpression="ProductID" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductCategory" DataField="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryNaame" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" SortExpression="Price" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:ImageField HeaderText ="ImageUrl" DataImageUrlField="ImageUrl" SortExpression="ImageUrl" ControlStyle-Width ="10">

        <ControlStyle Width="50px"></ControlStyle>

        </asp:ImageField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductQuantity" DataField="ProductQuantity" SortExpression="ProductQuantity" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProductSold" DataField="ProductSold" SortExpression="ProductSold" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AvailableStock" DataField="AvailableStock" SortExpression="AvailableStock" >
            <ItemStyle Height="20px" Width="150px" />
        </asp:BoundField>

        <%--<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True">
            <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:CommandField>--%>

        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" 
        OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm Delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="100px" />

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
```

and here is my code behind. Specifically the delete function:

```
protected void gdview_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        int prodid = int.Parse(gdview.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("", conn);
        conn.Open();
        da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("delete from Products where ProductID=" + prodid, conn);
        da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        GetProducts(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change code

```
int prodid = Convert.ToInt32(gdview.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["ProductID"].ToString());
```

from

```
int prodid = int.Parse(gdview.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: This is correct, but rather than just giving the code, I'd like to ask that you also add some explanation as to what the problem was and why your solution fixes it. It may seem trivial, but if the mistake was made in the first place, it evidently isn't trivial to everyone.

Comment: You have Provided gdview.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString() that it will not understand actual possition of row index that's why it was deleting randomly   by using this gdview.DataKeys[e.RowIndex] it will specify that on which id it's going to fire an event

Comment: Yep. You could put something like that in the actual answer for better visibility. This will help future readers. Thanks!